# Command not found

Tags: javascript, npm, vue.js, vue-cli

Been struggling to get my first vue project started and was looking for some help.
I have both npm and node updated on my system but continually keep falling to the same issue.

My steps:

1.) `npm install`
  ***Terminal Response:***

> npm WARN mbasile@1.0.0 No description
>   
>   up to date in 0.095s

2.) `npm install vue`
***Terminal Response:***

> npm WARN mbasile@1.0.0 No description
>   + vue@2.5.16
>   updated 1 package in 0.951s

**Here's where things get funky?**

---

3.) `npm install -g @vue/cli` 
***Terminal Response:***

> npm ERR! path /Users/mbasile/.npm-global/lib/node_modules//node_modules/.bin
>   npm ERR! code EACCES
>   npm ERR! errno -13
>   npm ERR! syscall rmdir
>   npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, rmdir '/Users/mbasile/.npm-global/lib/node_modules//node_modules/.bin'
>   npm ERR! { Error: EACCES: permission denied, rmdir '/Users/mbasile/.npm-global/lib/node_modules//node_modules/.bin'
>   npm ERR! cause:
>   npm ERR! { Error: EACCES: permission denied, rmdir '/Users/mbasile/.npm-global/lib/node_modules//node_modules/.bin'
>   npm ERR! errno: -13,
>   npm ERR! code: 'EACCES',
>   npm ERR! syscall: 'rmdir',
>   npm ERR! path: '/Users/mbasile/.npm-global/lib/node_modules//node_modules/.bin' },
>   npm ERR! stack: 'Error: EACCES: permission denied, rmdir '/Users/mbasile/.npm-global/lib/node_modules//node_modules/.bin'',
>   npm ERR! errno: -13,
>   npm ERR! code: 'EACCES',
>   npm ERR! syscall: 'rmdir',
>   npm ERR! path: '/Users/mbasile/.npm-global/lib/node_modules//node_modules/.bin' }
>   npm ERR!
>   npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
>   npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
>   npm ERR! /Users/mbasile/.npm/_logs/2018-05-09T17_53_06_030Z-debug.log

**So given this response I run**

---

4.) `sudo npm install -g @vue/cli`

***Terminal Response:***

> /Users/mbasile/.npm-global/bin/vue -> /Users/mbasile/.npm-global/lib/node_modules//bin/vue.js
>   + @3.0.0-beta.9
>   updated 1 package in 6.597s

5.) `vue create vue-project`
***Terminal Response:***

> -bash: vue: command not found

Leaving me a bit puzzled and confused here, but any help/response would be appreciated.

Answer (score 11):

I had this problem too and it was a little bit tricky to find a solution so I'll describe all the steps that helped me find a solution.

It's resolving a general problem with the wrong path for global packages in npm or missing path in shell variable `$PATH`.

**Fix for macOS Mojave but should work on all UNIX systems**

First of all, after installing the package globally npm will show you where a new package is installed.

```
$ npm i -g @vue/cli
/usr/local/Cellar/node/9.5.0/bin/vue -> /usr/local/Cellar/node/9.5.0/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/bin/vue.js
```

We can also check it in the npm config.

```
$ npm config get prefix
/usr/local/Cellar/node/9.5.0
```

So if after the global installation your terminal couldn't recognize the command *it's probably missing in your shell variable $PATH*. You can easily check it.

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

As we can see, the path from npm config isn't present in the shell variable `$PATH`.

Now we have two options to fix it.

**1. First option  - change *npm config***.

```
$ npm config set prefix '/usr/local'
$ npm config get prefix
/usr/local
```

After we changed the path in the config we will have to reinstall the desired package.

```
$ npm i -g @vue/cli
```

**2. Second option - add path from npm config  to *shell $PATH***

```
$ export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/Cellar/node/9.5.0
```

In this case, we don't need to install the package again.

Regardless of the selected option, we can now control if everything works.

```
$  vue --version
3.0.5
```

Comment: Thanks this is the most accurate solution!

Comment: For brew installed node (and thus, npm), the prefix is currently /usr/local/opt/nvm/versions/node/v12.6.0/bin or /usr/local/opt/nvm/versions/node/[node-version]/bin.  So, try adding `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/opt/nvm/versions/node/v12.6.0/bin` to your .bashrc, .bash_profile, .zshrc, or .zprofile (which should reside in your home directory).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is something wrong with npm

I recommend  you,first list all global npm packages to see if vue is installed with the command: `npm list -g --depth=0`

Then if vue is installed but again you get error try to delete vue with the command: `npm uninstall -g nameOfPackage`

Finally do it again from scratch: `npm install -g @vue/cli` and to create new project,navigate to directory you want to create the project and execute: `vue create nameOfProject`

Comment: Hi Roli, thank you for the response was able to trackdown two vue files labeled `@vue/cli@3.0.0-beta.9` and `vue-cli@2.9.3` but I was unable to uninstall them even while using `-f`. Wondering if you've experience that before?

Comment: Hey, @MattBasile sorry for the late, take a look here https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/uninstalling-global-packages

Comment: Hey Roli, sorry for my delay. But the docs were great was able to uninstall, and then reinstall. But was still unable to use `vue create vueProject` :(

Comment: Figured out the issue! Turns out my npm/node and directories we're not on the proper version and a bit out of whack. But I was able to use nvm to update both of them and eventually start up my vue project! Thank you for your help Roli definitely helped me get to my answer!

Comment: Glad to hear that you find a solution

Comment: @MattBasile can you post what you did exactly? I'm having the same issue. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do?

`npm install -g @vue/cli`

This is the command you should run on terminal to globally (-g) install vue command line interface.
After that you can do `vue create vue-project`

Comment: Hi Emils, sorry a typo on my side, but  yes been trying  npm install-g @vue/cli  and still haven't been able to   vue create vue-project