# Command not found with vue-cli

Tags: npm, vue.js, vue-cli

While installing the dependencies of vue-cli, vue is not identified. Why?

[image: error message while creating a project]

Comment: It looks like you need to add `/home/alisha/.local/bin` into your path, alternatively it could be that the current terminal session has not refreshed. Try restarting your terminal.

Comment: are you using nvm?

Comment: I found this really helpful:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50259593/command-not-found/52991711#52991711

Answer (score 34):

`rm -rf node_modules` and `npm install` again
[have a look here](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/2404)

Comment: thanks, this should be the right answer!

Answer (score 28):

I had the same issue for a while.

### TL;DR

```sh
 npm install @vue/cli-service --save-dev
```

As the documentation specify it is a development dependency  https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/#cli-service

> The CLI Service (@vue/cli-service) is a development dependency. It's an npm package installed locally into every project created by @vue/cli.

#### Origin

I had a fresh install of nodejs
And just did

```sh
>> sudo npm install -g @vue/cli@latest

>> vue --version
@vue/cli 4.5.8
```

#### The issue

The issue presented like this

```sh
>> npm run serve
yarn run v1.22.10
$ vue-cli-service build --mode development --watch
/bin/sh: 1: vue-cli-service: not found
error Command failed with exit code 127.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

#### The fixes:

```sh
npm install @vue/cli-service --save-dev
```

Which led me straight to another error message

```sh
>> npm run serve
yarn run v1.22.10
$ vue-cli-service build --mode development --watch
ERROR  Error: Cannot find module 'vue-template-compiler/package.json'
```

Which I fixed the same way

```sh
npm i vue-template-compiler --save-dev
```

And now it is working fine.

Answer (score 26):

Add `sudo` before yarn when installing

- `yarn global remove @vue/cli`
- `sudo yarn global add @vue/cli`
- `vue`

Comment: I can't believe this answer has 38 votes. Never use sudo with yarn or npm. That's a bad idea.

Comment: @NimeshkaSrimal  I think they just were looking for "just work" solution. Sure they will face permission problems in the future.

Comment: @NimeshkaSrimal  can you explain why so that we can learn.

Comment: @Bryan: It's fairly simple: `npm` pulls in easily hundreds if not thousands of modules. If you install these granting root permissions you can easily install a malicious script without noticing. Using `sudo` may seem like an easy way out - and it is - if you don't care about security at all. Unfortunately (and surprisingly), many developers don't care much about that (as we can see from this thread where using `sudo` is suggested in at least half of comments!). If my mother doesn't care I wouldn't mind but people reading this thread are developers. They SHOULD know better!

Comment: https://medium.com/@ExplosionPills/dont-use-sudo-with-npm-5711d2726aa3

Answer (score 20):

Installing current version without permanently installing vue-cli.

```
npx @vue/cli create appname
```

Answer (score 10):

It shows the vue executable is located at `/home/alisha/.local/bin`. So probably this location is not there in your `$PATH`.

You should be able to run the vue commands if you provide the full path, like:

`~/.local/bin/vue create hello-world`

You can also see if that directory is in your PATH by running some command like:

```
echo $PATH | grep '.local/bin/'
```

If it's there, you would see it, otherwise you can add it to your path by placing it in your `~/.profile`.

Edit `~/.profile` and add the following at the bottom of it.

```
PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"
```

Hope it helps!!

Comment: Their guidelines were good, for me only changed the locally: ~/.npm-global/bin/

Comment: after editing .profile run `source ~/.profile` to changes take effect on the current terminal

Comment: This is the only answer that actually helped me, thank you.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue while making a build for production.

You will require vue-cli to be installed. Use below command to install the latest version.

```
npm install -g @vue/cli@latest
```

Then

```
npm install
```

Comment: DON'T use sudo for installing anything with npm and DON'T encourage people to do so!

Answer (score 3):

Might have to do with you having an old version on your computer:

Warning regarding Previous Versions

The package name changed from vue-cli to @vue/cli. If you have the previous vue-cli (1.x or 2.x) package installed globally, you need to uninstall it first with 
npm uninstall vue-cli -g or yarn global remove vue-cli.

You can find it here: https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/installation.html

Answer (score 3):

THIS FIXED THE ISSUE FOR ME:

After running

`sudo npm install -g @vue/cli`

I ran

`sudo nano $HOME/.profile`

and pasted the following line

`export PATH=$PATH:/home/chike/.npm-global/bin`

after writing the code, next thing I did was `Ctrl + O`, `ENTER` and `Ctrl + X` then wrote

`vue init webpack myapp`

Answer (score 3):

> When you install vue using cli that time you got the path of vue.Now you can copy the bin folder path.
>    In my example **/home/sublime/.npm-packages/bin**
>
> Now you export the path below command

```
export PATH=$PATH:/home/sublime/.npm-packages/bin
```

Answer (score 3):

I solved mine by running (add `sudo` if needed)

- `npm i -g vue-cli@2.9.6`
- `npm i -g @vue/cli`

Comment: Same here as above: DON'T use `sudo` for installing anything with `npm` and DON'T encourage people to do so!

Answer (score 3):

Got similar issue when deploy vue project in jenkins.

Here is what I did:

Add node's `bin/` dir, to jenkins user's `.bashrc` file.

e.g

```
# node
NODE_HOME=/home/dev/.nvm/versions/node/default
PATH=$NODE_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

---

### Tips - about `nvm` & `yarn`

- When you manage node version via `nvm`, make sure you already choose the node version in terminal. e.g:
  `nvm use stable`
  `node -v`
- If you use nvm, and installed yarn via `npm`, then better install `vue-cli` via `npm` not `yarn`, otherwise the `vue` executable is not placed into node's `bin/` dir, at least that's the case in my tests, and as a result will cause you fail to find the `vue` command.

Answer (score 2):

Using Yarn on Ubuntu it is installed to `~/.npm-packages/bin/`. You must add this directory to your `PATH`. For example run the following command, close your terminal and open a new one.

```
user@machine:~$ echo 'export PATH="$PATH:~/.npm-packages/bin/"' >> ~/.bashrc
```

Note: if the file `~/.bashrc` does not exist then simply create it.

Comment: I found my binaries at `~/.yarn/bin/` **(not at ~/.npm-packages/bin/)**, checked by running `yarn global bin`.

Comment: And please note: Adding lines to `.bashrc` file will start to work on the next login. So, you have to re-login to make it work or by manually execute `export PATH="$PATH:~/.yarn/bin/`.

Answer (score 2):

Following worked for me:

First remove all the existing ones:

```
yarn global remove @vue/cli
yarn global remove @vue/cli-service
sudo yarn global remove @vue/cli
sudo yarn global remove @vue/cli-service
```

Then add `@vue/cli` using `sudo`:

**Note: use `sudo` if required**

```
yarn global add @vue/cli
```

```
yarn global add @vue/cli-service
```

Then, the final thing to do is to **RESTART** the terminal.

```
vue --version
@vue/cli 4.5.9
```

Answer (score 2):

If you already got a project, the only two things you need to do is:

1. Delete the directory node_modules (it is safe, since it is not under git and will regenerate in the next step)
2. In the command-line write `yarn install` (it will install everything you need)

If you start installing vue-cli manually in a existing project, it the package.json and package-lock.json will be updated. If you already did. Do a checkout from git, and follow my steps above

Comment: yarn ist not known/found.

Comment: Then you can achive the same using npm. Then the command is: npm install

Answer (score 2):

This may be a problem caused by version conflicts. "export PATH=$PATH:" This is really useful in some cases. But if you are also like me, after trying the direct “export path” method in the comment above, restarting the terminal still can not execute the situation, you can try this way.

1. Uninstall Vue

   ```
   npm uninstall -g @vue/cli
   ```
2. Check the local-global npm package installation path, vue is installed in this directory, check if it has been removed.

   ```
   npm root -g
   ```
3. Install vue (you can check with https://cli.vuejs.org/#getting-started to find the latest command)

   ```
   npm install -g @vue/cli
   ```
4. Create a connection to the /usr/local/bin directory(You need to find the vue.js path after the local installation first, then replace this path with your latest local install path:/Users/xxxxx/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/bin/vue.js)

   ```
   ln -s /Users/xxxxx/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/bin/vue.js /usr/local/bin/vue
   ```
5. View version number

   ```
   vue -V
   ```

Comment: vue -V (note: capital V)

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error because `Node.js` was not installed. My issue got resolved by installing `Node.js` using the following command:

```
sudo apt install nodejs-legacy
```

To see if you already have Node.js and npm installed and check the installed version, run the following commands:

```
node -v
npm -v
```

If both are installed then follow the steps here:
https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally

Answer (score 1):

I installed the package using `yarn global add @vue/cli` on my Ubuntu box and found the binary in `/home/vonkad/.yarn/bin`.

I had to modify my `/home/vonkad/.bashrc` and add the directory to the path `export PATH=$PATH:/home/vonkad/.yarn/bin`.

Answer (score 1):

To fix this situation, I had to add the following line to my `.zshrc` (maybe in your case is `.bashrc`)

```
export PATH="$(yarn global bin):$PATH"
```

Effectively, the `yarn global bin` is a folder where vue (vue-cli 3) was placed.

Comment: Add citation: [vue-cli-service: command not found](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/2404#issuecomment-423755641)

Answer (score 1):

If `npm install -g @vue/cli` was not help, then run

`npm i @vue/cli-service`. It creates vue-cli-service in your ./node_modules/.bin.

Answer (score 0):

What helped me

mac os catalina with zsh terminal

1. Uninstalled node and npm using https://www.positronx.io/how-to-uninstall-node-js-and-npm-from-macos/
2. Downloaded node/npm from https://nodejs.org/en/download/current/
3. sudo npm install -g @vue/cli
4. vue --version (@vue/cli 4.5.4)

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and now resolved. In my case I installed `Node.js` and `NPM` using the default Ubuntu repository by using this command `sudo apt-get install nodejs npm`

The problems seemed like those 2 packages are not well maintained so it caused some bugs.

So I `purge` those packages and reinstall it from `nodesource` which is officially recommended way to install (reference: [Installation instruction from nodesource](https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/blob/master/README.md)) using these commands.

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_14.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

Then reinstall `@vue/cli` again

```
sudo npm install -g @vue/cli
```

Now these issues have gone. Hope it helps some programmers.

Answer (score 0):

If you have WSL2 running and you use `zsh` like me, just add

```
yarn global add @vue/cli

# add this line to ~/.zshrc
export PATH="$HOME/.yarn/bin:$PATH"

$ vue --version
@vue/cli 4.x.xx
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to install vue via sudo like explained in the doc:
https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/installation.html
[image]

Comment: The screenshot/article you posted mentions nothing of sudo, that's just plain wrong.

Answer (score -4):

You can try the following code install see

```html
npm install --global vue-cli
vue init webpack <YOUR-PROJECT-NAME-HERE>
cd <YOUR-PROJECT-NAME-HERE>
npm install
npm run dev
```

Comment: This is proposing an install of an older version of the `vue-cli`, while the original post is about `vue-cli` 3